# Asignar evento a atributo inventodo con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs, json, vue.js

Hola se le puede asignar un evento con Jquery a un atributo HTML inventodo, como en este caso

```
<td><button idAddTarjeta="${tarjeta.setID()}" class="btnAgregar">Agregar</button></td>
<td><button idDeleteTarjeta="${tarjeta.setID()}" class="btnDelete">Eliminar</button></td>
```

yo le quiero asignar un evento a esos atributos (idAddTarjeta y idDeleteTarjeta), ya que no puedo ponerles ID porque se repetirian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer uso de los **atributos de datos** de **HTML5**. Estos te pueden servir para precisamente lo que buscas, añadir meta-datos a tus elementos para después usarlos desde **Javascript**.

Luego, a través de la función `data()` de JQuery puedes acceder a ellos de manera cómoda.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.btnAgregar').click(function() {
    const elemento = $(this);
    const idTarjeta = elemento.data('id-tarjeta');
    
    console.log('Se agrega', idTarjeta);
  });
  
  $('.btnDelete').click(function() {
    const elemento = $(this);
    const idTarjeta = elemento.data('id-tarjeta');
    
    console.log('Se borra', idTarjeta);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td><button data-id-tarjeta="122" class="btnAgregar">Agregar</button></td>
<td><button data-id-tarjeta="122" class="btnDelete">Eliminar</button></td>
```

**Referencias:** [Atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Hola @phpMyGuel gracias por ayudarme, pero me surgio un problema al utilizar el atributo data en JQuery con el evento click(
e.data('id')
e.target.data('id')
)con estos 2 intentos solo obtengo puros errores

Comment: La función `data()` es de JQuery y con `event.target` obtienes un objeto que no es de JQuery, por lo que no podrías usarla sobre este. Dentro de una función `click()` de JQuery, para obtener el elemento que la está disparando, es a través de `$(this)`, tal y como aparece en mi ejemplo.

Comment: Si perfecto, lo pude hacer con otra funcion dataset, pero re bien, gracias..!